# JavaScript regex test if string contains specific word (with variable)

Tags: javascript, regex, string-comparison

I have a regex to check if a string contains a specific word. It works as expected:

```
/\bword\b/.test('a long text with the desired word amongst others'); // true
/\bamong\b/.test('a long text with the desired word amongst others'); // false
```

But i need the word which is about to be checked in a variable. Using `new RegExp` does not work properly, it always returns `false`:

```
var myString = 'a long text with the desired word amongst others';

var myWord = 'word';
new RegExp('\b' + myWord + '\b').test(myString); // false

myWord = "among";
new RegExp('\b' + myWord + '\b').test(myString); // false
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
var myWord = 'word';
new RegExp('\\b' + myWord + '\\b')
```

You need to double escape the `\` when building a regex from a string.

---

This is because `\` begins an escape sequence in a string literal, so it never makes it to the regex. By doing `\\`, you're including a literal `'\'` character in the string, which makes the regex `/\bword\b/`.

Comment: +1, see http://jsfiddle.net/TxQ7c/6/

Comment: Figured it out at the same time you posted your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Uri: Not sure what that has to do with this answer.